# A browsersync task with npm scripts is not refreshing browser after file changes

Tags: npm, browser-sync, build-tools, npm-scripts

I'm encountering an issue with using an npm scripts task to launch a `browsersync` server which refreshes after file updates...

A task named `serve` is defined in the `scripts` property of the `package.json` as follows:

```json
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "browser-sync start --server \"dev\" --files \"./dev/css/*.css, ./dev/js/*.js, ./dev/*.html\" --browser \"Google Chrome\""
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.17.0"
    }
}
```

My directory is structured as follows:

```
project
│
├── package.json
│
├─── dev
│   │
│   ├───index.html
│   │
│   ├─── css
│   │   │
│   │   └───style.css
│   │
│   └─── js
│       │
│       └───main.js
│
└─── node_modules
    │
    ├───browser-sync
    │
    ├───browser-sync-client
    │
    ├───browser-sync-ui
    │
    └─── ...
```

When I `cd` to the `project` directory and type `npm run serve` the `browsersync` server correctly starts, opens `index.html` via `http://localhost:3000/` in the Chrome browser.

If I then edit either `index.html`, `style.css`, or `main.js` and save the changes `browsersync` DOES NOT auto refresh to reflect those changes in the browser.

Interestingly, after I run the same command (i.e. the same as specified in the `package.json` without escaping the double quotes) directly via the CLI as follows:

`$ browser-sync start --server "dev" --files "./dev/css/*.css, ./dev/js/*.js, ./dev/*.html" --browser "Google Chrome"`

...the browser correctly opens `index.html` and after editing saving changes to either `index.html`, `style.css`, or `main.js` `browsersync` DOES currectly refresh the browser.

The version of `browsersync` I have installed both globally and locally (i.e. within the project folder) are the same version (2.17.0).

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly in scripts section of the `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem today, I wanted to set up a simple file to do tests.

The way it worked for me was to remove the escape characters and add the routes directly:

Example:

```
 .....
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "browser-sync start --server --files ./**/*",
  }
 .....
```

I am serving all files in the current folder

[Here I am aware of how npm uses the paths inside the commands](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path)